# openshift CNAME for .tk

Tags: openshift, tk-toolkit, cname

I like to know how i could park .tk domain on openshift .
i have made an alliance for my :
diy-phpfm4nginx.rhcloud.com     domain in openshfit console.
i enterde my-domain.tk as alias in .tk and set tk CNAME setting like bellow:

***nothing(i mean i have placed it empty!) ---> CNMAE----TTL=14440,Target=my-domain.rhcloud.com***

***www---> CNMAE----TTL=14440,Target=my-domain.rhcloud.com***

you could see page images in:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/33c0ytj.jpg

and it works. so in openshift sites they have advised to use domain forwarding because they said : only "www." would work,but "http://" would not work for .tk domains work. SO have it is possible when it worked form me.
if you like , you could look at the :

> Try using domain forwarding instead. Reason being, you are able to
>   use CNAME records for www.yourdomain.tk, but not for yourdomain.tk
>   since the service doesn't allow it.

i like to know am i misunderstand CNAME setting, or i am Right.

Finally ( inside of .tk naked domain ability ) i found some 3d redirect part for redirecting naked domain to www. domain you could see more details here:
http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect
thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: that image is not clear,

Comment: I think .tk works with NAKED Domains. because it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway from reading your question and i think you wanted to achieve

> nothing.com ---> my-domain.rhcloud.com

For the above case `(naked domain)` === you either need to use Domain Forwarding or find a DNS provider that allows `"Naked"` CName records.

for the sub domain like `www.nothing.com` set `rhc alias add` will work for you.